# How to rewrite this "check, assign and return" pattern?

Tags: kotlin

Is there any clearer, more idiomatic way to rewrite this "check, assign and return" function?

```
fun getX(): Y {
    if (X == null) {
        X = ...
    }

    return X!!
}
```

**Edit**: I know of Elvis operator but the problem is that although I can save on few lines with syntax sugar

```
fun getX(): Y {
    X = X ?: ...
    return X!!
}
```

I'm not changing the semantics of the code. I need to force casting anyway (`!!`). So it's the same, just three lines shorter.

**Edit**: `X` is a property on some object, and I need to update it.

Comment: Do you need the assignation? If not, just `return X != null ? X!! : ...`

Comment: Unfortunately, yep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `by lazy` i.e. a property that is initialized the first time it is called. See [Delegated Properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) and [lazy initialization tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-lazy-initialization)

```
val x :String by lazy {
    "a"
}
```

or in your case:

```
val z : Y by lazy {
    y!!
}
```

You might also want to have a look at [lateinit-properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables):

```
lateinit val y : Y
```

Comment: Still this will throw a NPE and should only be used if you are working with legacy libraries where you can not be sure that y is not null.

Answer (score 5):

You can move assignment to the right hand side of the elvis operator using `also` function:

```
fun getX() = x ?: valueIfXisNull.also { x = it }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Elvis Operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator): `?:`

> If the expression to the left of ?: is not null, the elvis operator returns it, otherwise it returns the expression to the right.

You can update your variable with the elvis operator then return the result.

```
fun getX(): Y {
    x = x ?: valueIfNull   // If x is null, x becomes 'valueIfNull'.
    return x!!             // x cannot be null, return it.
}
```

Comment: The thing is, I need to assign to X, not only return something.

Comment: I believe he wants to assign value when null, not return other value

Comment: Oops my bad. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I updated my question. I know that ?: is an improvement, but I'm wondering if I can do it fundamentally different way.